# Quando utilizar Cordova ou Xamarin?

Tags: apache-cordova, xamarin

Ao pesquisar um pouco sobre plataformas para o desenvolvimento de aplicativos *mobile* acabei me deparando com o Xamarin e o Cordova.

Ambos tem como proposta desenvolver uma única base de código para aplicativos que rodam em Android, iOS e Windows Phone.

Como não sou *expert* em desenvolvimento *mobile* me surgiram as seguintes dúvidas:

- Quais as principais diferenças entre essas plataformas?
- É possível utilizar os recursos nativos que são exclusivos de determinado sistema operacional?
- As plataformas são compatíveis entre si?

Comment: Só lembrando que ele não quer saber qual é o melhor, qual você gosta mais. Responda objetivamente se entende dos dois minimamente se puder dar um resposta sem ser tendenciosa.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Xamarim é para criares aplicações nativas moveis (Android, Windows Phone e iOS) usando a linguagem da Microsoft `C#`.

Cordova (ou como era chamado antigamente: PhoneGap) é  o mesmo mas usando `Javascript`

**Ambos funcionam como um proxy** ao chamar funções internas seja de que dispositivo móvel, eles internamente chamam o method certo, seja se estiverem a correr em Android, WPhone ou iOS, onde nós programadores, chamamos apenas um método.

Não querendo entrar no debate, qual a melhor linguagem, se C# ou JavaScript, será com o próprio programador de como quererá e para que fins será a sua aplicação.

Xamarim, <strike>[precisas de uma licença](https://store.xamarin.com/)</strike> [é gratuito](http://news.thewindowsclub.com/xamarin-free-visual-studio-83044/) desde Abril de 2016 (pois a [Microsoft adquiriu a Xamarin](https://blog.xamarin.com/a-xamarin-microsoft-future/)), e tem o proprio IDE ([Xamarim Studio](http://xamarin.com/studio) e Visual Studio), Cordova é gratuito.

**Xamarim** integra-se na compilação do código pelo que podes fazer seja que aplicação for incluindo jogos nativos, enquanto, **Cordova** corre num painel Web, ou seja, a aplicação será sempre uma página web onde então podes executar os comandos em JavaScript e "desenhar" em HTML5 e CSS3, ou seja, tudo o que poderes fazer em web, podes correr com o Cordova.

---

**Quais as principais diferenças entre essas plataformas?**

O principal objectivo do *Xamarin* é trazer programadores de .NET para iOS, pois a linguagem é C#. São conhecidos por, sempre que a Apple expõem novos API's, em menos de 24 horas estão disponíveis em Xamarim. Com o Xamarim, podemos criar qualquer aplicação nativa, e agora como suporta Android e Windows Phone também, podemos ter as nossas próprias livrarias da nossa aplicacao (BLL e DAL por exemplo) e criar apenas "Views" para Web e com Xamarin, Android, iOS e WP, nunca saindo da linguagem C#, e sem nunca precisar de aprender Java, Swift ou Objective C.

*Cordova* segue mais o principio de "mobile app" pois é a continuação do PhoneGap, que podíamos fazer uma applicação web e correr-la num browser, sendo que sem Cordova, não se pode chamar comandos do telefone, como a Lista de Contactos, a Galeria de Fotos pois estamos "bloqueados" apenas ao que o browser do telefone suporta, por exemplo os links `tel:` e `mailto:` que abre a aplicação Telefone e Email respectivamente.

**É possível utilizar os recursos nativos que são exclusivos de determinado sistema operacional?**

Sim, ambos tem ferramentas internas que converte as chamadas em chamadas nativas, mas o Cordova, apenas tem algumas uma vez que apenas correr como uma Página Web. Já o Xamarim tem todas as chamadas nativas dos 3 principais sistemas moveis, uma vez que tem a capacidade de criar todo o tipo de aplicações e não só WebApps.

**As plataformas são compatíveis entre si?**

São duas coisas distintas, não sabendo os teus recursos como programador, digo-te por outras palavras:

- com o Xamarim, podes criar um carro de raiz
- com o Cordova, podes apenas criar a visualização do painel de instrumentos

Comment: O que seria exatamente um carro de raíz ?

Comment: @gmsantos ele quer dizer que você pode criar do zero, das camadas mais baixas e com cordova você vai ficar limitado a camadas mais superficiais.

Eu já utilizei os dois, se você quer fazer algo simples que não precise de muito desempenho, Cordova é uma boa escolha. Mas se precisar de mais controle e desemprenho, Xamarin é uma escolha melhor.

Mas também tem seu lado negativo, como dito, pe pago ou seja, se você começar uma aplicação, prepara o bolso e atualmente vejo que quando você encontra um erro, leva um tempinho pra conseguir resolver (estou fazendo isso desde ontem)

Comment: Mas o fato de utilizar apenas o C# é muito bom. Nada contra outras linguagens, mas o código fica mais simples, na minha opinião.

Na dúvida da uma olhada. Se for estudante você consegue uma licença gratuita.

Comment: @ItaloPessoa interessante a licença de estudante, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: http://xamarin.com/student

Comment: Xamarin agora é gratuito https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/. Além disso a resposta está parcialmente errada sobre cordova não poder fazer chamadas nativas, através de plugins você pode acessar qualquer funcionalidade nativa desejada, veja https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/hybrid/plugins/.

Comment: @BrunoRB verdade, conseguiria incluir uma nova resposta ou editar? Talvez se o balexandre não se manifestar seja melhor transformar em uma resposta wiki

Comment: @gmsantos editei para que contenha os links da adquisicao da Xamarin pela Microsoft e disse que agora não é necessário uma licensa :)