# O que é Native Script?

Tags: javascript, mobile, nativescript

Recentemente li sobre Native Script, queria saber um pouco mais sobre e como funciona.

O que é o Native Script?

Quais são as vantagens?

Como funciona?

Vale a pena usar?

Enquanto sua curva de aprendizado?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

É mais uma tentativa de oferecer uma ferramenta que permita desenvolver aplicações multiplataforma especialmente focada em dispositivos móveis (iOS, Android e Windows).

Ela é baseada em JavaScript e dá acesso às APIs nativas de cada plataforma de maneira uniforme. Esta é uma vantagem em relação ao desenvolvimento web que tem várias restrições ao acesso dos recursos do dispositivo, além de ficar com muita cara de web, eventualmente até prejudicando a usabilidade.

Ela não garante que 100% da aplicação será multiplataforma, mas grande parte será escrita apenas uma vez deixando uma porção marginal que deve ser escrita de forma mais específica para uma plataforma. Acredito ser uma abordagem interessante, só não sei o quanto conseguiram fazer de forma satisfatória.

É importante que são geradas aplicações nativas, não é uma aplicação web. JavaScript é apenas a linguagem de escrita. não é a infraestrutura toda. Isto difere do [PhoneGap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/79939/101) que é usado para desenvolver multiplataforma, mas se vale primariamente da web para atingir o objetivo.

Na verdade ele se assemelha mais ao [Xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90871/101) que também fornece acesso nativo às APIs de cada plataforma quando C# ou outras linguagens .NET como linguagem. Aparentemente há a vantagem de não precisar de *wrappers* então qualquer novidade da plataforma está disponível imediatamente para o [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/). Ainda que eu duvide que funcione tão bem assim, parece um pouco de marketing. Também prometem ter uma base única para a UI. Até hoje não vi uma solução que funcionasse bem assim. Esta é a primeira?

A curva de aprendizado parece ser pequena se já **domina** bem **JavaScript** e entende o modelo de desenvolvimento para mobile. Mas ainda precisará aprender as novas APIs. Se vale a pena só a pessoa pode dizer, eu não sei nem pra mim se vale :P

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, acho que vou entrar nessa :D

Comment: Eu levei anos para me sentir a vontade para desenvolver Mobile, e quando conheci o NativeScript achei a solução, tem sido uma experiência muito boa.

Comment: O xamarin até entendo como funciona, pois roda sobre uma VM (no caso android por exemplo, é uma vm mono) como li na documentação. Mas como isso acontece com NS? Ele gera código java e compila? Tem uma vm v8 que chama as api nativas?

Comment: Não sei dizer sobre ele. Eu acho que o Xamarin não roda em VM, é código nativo binário direto mesmo, ele apenas se comunica com a VM do Java. Só não afirmo porque eu posso estar confundindo como Xamarin para iOS que roda sem VM com certeza.

Comment: Hum, pesquisando melhor, achei um artigo explicando um pouco melhor a minha dúvida http://developer.telerik.com/featured/nativescript-works/.

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net achei que era isto, mas não tinha certeza.

Comment: A e sobre o xamarin, pelo que entendi aqui, ele usa vm sim, tanto no android como no ios: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_1_-_understanding_the_xamarin_mobile_platform/

Comment: @Juniorc-Sharp-Asp.Net lá está escrito que no iOS é nativo mesmo.

Comment: Então viajei mesmo, mas tinha lido em algum outro blog, que o código no ios tambem era executado sobre uma vm, só não lembro qual. Mas não ficou claro como ele transforma código c# em código nativo para o ios. Você sabe?

Comment: O compilador gera o código binário, nenhum segredo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59584/discussion-between-juniorc-sharp-asp-net-and-bigown).